# Strange behaviour with wchar_t* based vector

Tags: c++, winapi, vector, stl

I'm developing a small function, which iterates through a directory and places the names of all files into a `wchar_t*` based vector:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>

#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;

    std::wstring sDir(L"D:\\Test");
    sDir += L"\\*"; 

    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(sDir.c_str(), &ffd);

    std::vector<wchar_t*> vctsFiles;
    wchar_t szBuf[MAX_PATH];

    do
    {
        if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {
            memset(szBuf, 0, sizeof(szBuf));
            ::PathCombine(szBuf, L"D:\\Test", ffd.cFileName);
            vctsFiles.push_back(szBuf);
        }

    } while(FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that all entries in the vector get overwritten, as soon as a new file name is appended. In other words, all vector entries will contain identical values.

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, since I'm always clearing the buffer before using it for a new entry. Is there a way to remedy this behavior? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You re-use the same buffer, but peek putting its address on the vector again and again. Instead, you need new strings. Why not use a `std::vector<std::wstring>`?

Comment: Oh, and it is not strange behavior once you understand what it is doing (in other words, it is working perfectly fine, just not how you were expecting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector is a vector of pointers, and they all point to the same place (`szBuf`).  You need to allocate a `new szBuf` each time, or better, use a vector of wstring.

```
std::vector<std::wstring> vctsFiles;
```

Comment: or std::array since the buffer size is fixed

Comment: @paulm um, no. The number of *directories* would be unknown, so you would not use `std::array`.

Comment: @crashmstr: I believe paulm means `std::array<wchar_t,MAX_PATH>` in place of `std::wstring`, not in place of the vector. (not that I agree)

Comment: @MrZebra Unfortunately, a `std::vector<std::wstring>` is not possible, since the vector will be exported to a C dll, which accepts a `wchar_t**` input argument. Would it nevertheless be possible to work with fixed arrays, instead of resorting to dynamic allocation?

Comment: Exactly what @Benjamin Lindley said :) You can easily wrap a C interface around either of these, pointer to element 0 for std::array or std::string::c_str.

Comment: @Aurora you can only work with fixed arrays if you are willing to limit the maximum number of directories, for example ditch the vector completely and use `wchar_t szBuf[500][1024]`.